# Unable to connect to Backend to nodejs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am Unable to connect to Backend While I am giving valid Credentials from front End
I am Facing this error  :  POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login 400 (Bad Request)
I am Able to Generate the Token from Backend End , But not able to login from Fornt-end and getting Invalid credentials , although I am giving same like this : {
"email" : "Sandi6008@gmail.com",
"password" :14280
}

here is my Backend Code Nodejs Code :

```
router.post('/login', async(req,res) =>{
    try {
        const {email,password} =req.body;
         let exist = await Auth.findOne({email}) 
         if(!exist){
             return res.status(400).json("User Not Found");
         }
         if(exist.password !== password){ 
          return res.status(400).json('Invalid Credentails');
         }
            let payload = {
                user : {
                    id  : exist.id
                }
            }
            jwt.sign(payload,'jwtSecret',{expiresIn : 3600000}, (err,token)=>
                if (err) throw err;
                return res.json({token})
            })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error : error.msg})
    }
})
```

Here is the MongoDB Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');



const AuthSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    username :{
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    email :{
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    },
    password :{
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    confirmpassword :{
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    created :{
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now()
    }
});

let Auth = mongoose.model('auth' , AuthSchema);
module.exports = Auth;
```

here is the Forntend Login Page

```
import React,{useState,useContext} from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { store } from './../../App';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

 const Login = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        email : '',
        password : '',
     })

     const handleChange = (e) =>{
         setData({...data,[e.target.name] : e.target.value});
     }

     const submitForm =(e) =>{
          e.preventDefault();
         //console.log(data);
         axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login',data).then(res => console.log(res.data));
     }

  return (
    <div>
    <div className="container mt-3">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header bg-info text-white">
              <h4>Login</h4>
              <hr className="bg-white border-3 border-top border-white"></hr>
              <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label fw-bold">Email</label>
                  <input name="email" className="form-control" placeholder='Email' onChange={handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label fw-bold">Passowrd</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder='Passowrd' name="Passowrd" onChange={handleChange} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark fw-bold mt-4">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Here is the Code for Registration
here is the code for Registration

```
router.post('/register', async(req,res) =>{
   try {
       const {username,email,password,confirmpassword} = req.body;
       //First we need to check wheather is the Email Id is exists or not?
       let exist = await Auth.findOne({email});
       if(exist){
           return res.status(400).json({msg : 'User is alreday exists'});
       }
       if(password !== confirmpassword){
        return res.status(400).json({msg : 'Passwords are not matching'});
       }

        let newUser = new Auth({
            username,
            email,
            password,
            confirmpassword
        })
         await newUser.save();
         res.status(200).send({msg : 'Register Successfully'})
   } catch (error) {
       res.status(500).json({error : error.msg})
   }
```

})

Comment: probably because you have misspelled the `name="Passowrd"` in the form

Comment: You are comparing plain text passwords. Probably the password stored on the database has been encrypted on registration. Can you post the code handling the registration of a new user?

Comment: @lpizzinidev
 Please find the code for  Registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be caused by the different types of password during comparison since you are storing them as `Number`.
Try to cast both of them to a string with `.toString()`:

```
if(exist.password.toString() !== password.toString()) { 
    return res.status(400).json('Invalid Credentails');
}
```

Also, I see that you are saving passwords in plain text, which is a pretty bad security issue.
Check out some libraries that allow you to hash the stored passwords, like [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Your code for registration will become:

```
// Generate encrypted password
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(12);
const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

let newUser = new Auth({
    username,
    email,
    password: encryptedPassword,
    confirmpassword: encryptedPassword
});
```

And you will check your password during login with:

```
const isValidPsw = await bcrypt.compare(password, exist.password);
if (!isValidPsw) {
    return res.status(400).json('Invalid Credentails');
}
```